# Avoiding LIKE Operator in SQL Queries

Tags: sql, t-sql, full-text-search, database-performance, sql-like

Is there any other way I can write the query for avoiding using "LIKE" operator, as LIKE usage effects Performance while searching large amount of data.

My Table:

```
Products
--------
Id int
ProductName NVARCHAR(255)
```

Qry: Seraching for products which contains word "EBS"

```
select * from Products where name like 'EBS%'
```

A full-text index is placed on the Products table. For few products im not able to retrieve data from PRODUCTS Table thru full-text index.

```
select *
from Products 
WHERE contains(ProductName,@Contains)
Order by    MT.Name
```

-- No Results for the above qry
select * from Products where name like 'EBS%'  ( Poor performance)
so there is anyother way to implement this.

Comment: Why dont you use Full Text ?

Answer (score 0):

Full Text works on full words (tokens), or prefix tokens at best, but not on arbitrary partial matches. For 'contains arbitrary string' there is no workaround, only a slow scan using `LIKE`. Usually the solution is to go to the requirement stakeholders and push back on unjustified demands.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a regular index on the `name` field.  SQL Server will use an index when the pattern starts with a constant string.

So, this will use the index:

```
select *
from Products
where name like 'EBS%';
```

This will not:

```
select *
from Products
where name like '%EBS%';
```

Answer (score 0):

on SQL Server this could fit:

```
select * from Products where LEFT(name,3) = 'EBS'
```